# .htaccess redirect loop after website rebuild

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have rebuilt a website with new page paths and a file/directory structure that reflects the paths.  The new website is php based so all the page filenames are appended with ".php", but I am hiding the .php extension from the public paths.

The old website had a homepage for Spanish speakers at www.somedomain.com/es.  The new website has a homepage for Spanish speakers at www.somedomain.com/es/inicio.php.  The inicio.php file is now within a directory called '/es'.

My .htaccess reads :

```
Redirect 301 /es/node/64 http://www.somedomain.com/es/vacaciones-y-actividades/actividades-locales

Redirect 301 /es http://www.somedomain.com/es/inicio

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

The page requests are successfully rewritten with .php appended as intended.  Redirections like the first one work fine.  However navigating to http://www.somedomain.com/es causes a redirect loop.

Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navigating to http://www.somedomain.com/es causes a Redirect loop error for you because  your `Redirect` pattern `/es` also matches the destination path `/es/inicio` .  You need to fix it so that your pattern doesn't match the destination path.  use `RedirectMatch` and  regex pattern to fix this.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/es/?$ http://example.com/es/initio
```

clear your browser cache or use a diffrent browser to test this if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks.  That works although my limited regex means I don't know how.  Is this to do with greedyness ?